# Get reference of the object from a separate class

Tags: java, oop

Currently, there are 3 classes which are not inheriting to each other. Each class has a property in it that references to an instance of another class as below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Region {
    private Directory areaDirectory;

    public Region() {
        areaDirectory = new Directory();
    }

    public Directory getAreaDirectory() {
        return areaDirectory;
    }

    public void setAreaDirectory(Directory areaDirectory) {
        this.areaDirectory = areaDirectory;
    }
}

class Directory {
    private ArrayList<Area> areaList;

    public Directory() {
        areaList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Area> getAreaList() {
        return areaList;
    }

    public void setAreaList(ArrayList<Area> areaList) {
        this.areaList = areaList;
    }

    public Area addNewArea(){
        Area area = new Area();
        return area;
    }
}

class Area {
    private String Name;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Region getAreaRegion() {
        // This returns a new region but need the region it was created in
        return new Region();
    }
}


public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Region r = new Region();
        Area a = r.getAreaDirectory().addNewArea();
        a.setName("Demo");

        //See getAreaRegion() method in Area class
        System.out.println(a.getAreaRegion());
    }
}
```

How to implement a method like getAreaRegion() such that it returns the region object `r`? How to setup inheritance in this example to get parent objects?

Comment: The only way an `Area` object can return its own `Region` is if it knows its own `Region`. Give the `Area` class a field `private Region region`, and add a constructor parameter which sets that field. Change the `addNewArea()` method to return `new Area(region)`. The `Directory` class will therefore need to know its own `Region` too, so you'll need to change that class similarly.

Comment: Since i created the `Area object` from a reference of the `Region` object, can't it somehow return its reference object back without explicitly setting it, like using `this`?

Comment: An area object doesn't *have* a region, unless you say that it does by declaring a field for it.

Comment: Any way to setup inheritance in this scenario to get the desired result?

Comment: None of these classes has a field of type `Region` that you could inherit. If you want an object to hold a reference to a `Region`, then you need to declare a field to hold that reference. `this` is a special case because it refers to the object itself; an object doesn't need to store a reference to itself because it is itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have understood the business logic which you want to describe with codes as below:

There is a region. Every region has a directory. And every directory has an area.
In this case I think it would be nice if :

- Region class holds reference to Directory field;
- And Directory class also has reference for its own Region;
- Directory class holds reference to Area field;
- And Area class also has reference for its own Directory.

Then we can create classes in following way:

1.Region class

```
public class Region {
private Directory directory;

public Directory getDirectory() {
    return directory;
}

public void setDirectory(Directory directory) {
    this.directory = directory;
}
}
```

2.Directory class

```
class Directory{
private Region region;
private Area area;

public Region getRegion() {
    return region;
}

public void setRegion(Region region) {
    this.region = region;
}

public Area getArea() {
    return area;
}

public void setArea(Area area) {
    this.area = area;
}
}
```

3.Area class

```
class Area{
private Directory directory;
private String Name;

public Directory getDirectory() {
    return directory;
}

public void setDirectory(Directory directory) {
    this.directory = directory;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}
}
```

So we can get region of area as following:

```
area.getDirectory().getRegion();
```

I think this shows business logic better and simply. Hope it would be helpful for someone:)